# Cast List<Rows> to List<long> in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I have query cassandra table and selected curent_time as shown below:

```
 Dataset getTime = spark.sql("select current_time from trafficdata where current_time between "+ time1 +" and "+ time2 );
 getTime.show();
 List<Rows> list = getTime.collectAsList();
```

I want to convert this `List<Rows>` to `List<Long>`. Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: does the rows element have an id and this id is Long type element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cast `List<Row>` to `List<Long>`, but you can convert it.

One thing: `Dataset.collectAsList` returns `List<T>`, for `Dataset<Row>` it would be `List<Row>`, not `List<Rows>` - probably typo.

You can do:

```
List<Long> longs = new ArrayList<>();
for(Row row : list) {
    longs.add(row.getLong(0));
}
```

Java 8 Stream option:

```
List<Long> longs = list.stream().map(row -> row.getLong(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are unclear from your description, but i'm going to assume that you are not running java 8 and that current_time is a Datetime type.
so:

```
ArrayList<Long> newlist = new ArrayList();
for(Datetime d : list) {
    newlist.add(d.getMillis());
} 
return newlist;
```

Comment: i am running java 8 and the current_time is Long . the for loop gives incompatible types error. required :org.apache.spark.sql.Row found java.util.Long

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to extract that `long` value from your `Rows`? If yes, you can use something like

```
final List<Long> timeList = getTime.collectAsList()
    .stream()
    .map(r -> getLongValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assuming that you replace `getLongValue` function with an actual one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because there is no inheritance between `List<Rows>` and `List<Long>`.

You must read a little of [Generics Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)